# getline() in c changing my data and causing memory errors

Tags: c, file-io

I'm trying to write a C program in Xcode (5.0.2) to do read in a file and do some math with it, and I'm hoping someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong. My code reads in each line of a csv (tried txt, same issues), performs some calculations with it, and then discards the line.

The calculations seem to work fine, but I'm having trouble with getline() acting weird. This is my function:

```
void fileRead(int** matrixOfResults) {
    char filePath[] = "/path/to/file.csv";
    FILE * file;
    char fileMode[] = "r";
    ssize_t linelen;
    size_t linecap = 0;
    char *line = NULL;

    file = fopen(filePath, fileMode);
    while ((linelen = getline(&line, &linecap, file)) > 0) {
        // reads line and does the math. doesn't seem to cause problems
        performSomeCalculations(line, matrixOfResults); 
        free(line);
        line = NULL;
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

Every time I run it, it fails in a different place (yay variety!). It reads in some of the lines perfectly fine, but then crashes, usually somewhere between lines 50-200.

One place it goes wrong is misreading my input data. Here is one example:

```
(char *) line = 0x0000000100300080 "26,581,856,1029,1598,1856,3000,4567,6742,7013,8293,8365,8696,9055,9064,9496,9497,10698,10830,**10975,20886**,11294,11452,12040,12630,13757,13991\n"
```

I checked the same line in the original file, where it was:

```
26,581,856,1029,1598,1856,3000,4567,6742,7013,8293,8365,8696,9055,9064,9496,9497,10698,10830,**10875,10886**,11294,11452,12040,12630,13757,13991
```

It also seems to change , to - quite often, as well as change numbers to colons.

I'm also getting a bunch of `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` errors, primarily when either assigning line in the while, or while trying to free the line. The `performSomeCalculations` function takes line as a `const`, so it's not getting modified somewhere.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. The design of `getline()` is that you don't need to free the memory on each iteration; you'll probably do better not to.  Free the memory after the loop.  Since you don't show that you're printing the line after `getline()` returns and before and after calling `performSomeCalculations()`, why should we think that it is `getline()` doing the damage and not `performSomeCalculations()`?

Comment: Suspect `performSomeCalculations()`.  Comment out and see if you still have problems.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass a valid value in the second parameter, see [the documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Line-Input.html). This [in,out] parameter returns the size of the buffer after the call. But it should also indicate the size of the buffer. When you `free` the memory and set the pointer in the first parameter to NULL you must set linecap to zero.

`char **lineptr` and `size_t *n` is a pair of parameters that pass the address and the size of the line buffer. Your code treats them different when you delete with changing the size information.

The better aproach would to let `line` and `linecap` untouched until the end of the loop. It's suffucient to delete it finally.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem; the OP is passing a pointer to null each time.  Inside `getline()`, the value `*lineptr` corresponds to the value in `line` in the calling code; it can be passed to `realloc()` because a null pointer can be passed to `realloc()` and it acts like `malloc()` when that happens. Although `getline()` and `getdelim()` were once GNU extensions, they are now POSIX standard.  You might be able to argue that the length should be zeroed as well as the pointer nullified; POSIX does not require that, but GNU might (judging from the page you reference).